# Why does my div boxes stack downwards when i have set a float left?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a webstore and i want to have like a product field with product in it and i want them to float left so when i add a product it floats left with the rest of the products.

**PROBLEM**

When i add a float: left it stacks downwards instead of floating left and i dont understand why?

**EXAMPLE**

[Example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zz3Cm.png)

**CODE:**

```css
.product_gallery {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}

.product_gallery li {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  margin-right: 50;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.product_gallery li img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  float: right;
}

.product_description {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in;
}

.product_gallery li:hover .product_description {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.product_description p {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.product_information {
  height: 40px;
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.product_information h4 {
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 10px;
}

.product_information span {
  float: right;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.buy_now {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  width: 85px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
  height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="product_gallery">
  <li>
    <img src="images/test.png">
    <div class="product_information">
      <h4>AWP ASIIMOV</h4>
      <span>230:-</span>
    </div>
    <div class="product_description">
      <p>Awp asiimov är ett fint skin om man gillar att spela awp :)</p>
      <a href="#" class="buy_now">BUY NOW</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I truly understand you, you want your divs are side by side.Now it is not, because the first div has `width: 100%`, So the second div goes to next line.

Decrease its width to a value that can contain in one line with div `width: 300px`.